# How to populate many to many relationship

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a MANY-to-MANY relation between two models. But I cannot figure out how to create a form or table to add records to a many to many relation. I am using Google Drive Tables.

I tried to see if the relation is well set, I exported the data and manually populated the keys in the sheet created for the many to many relation. I checked  using dropdowns to filter data and it works well.

This is probably basic but I just can't find out how to do it. Please help.

Mauricio

Comment: Add a snippet with the @Entity that you have created.

Comment: Actually, there are different ways to implement this and different approaches can look different. What are your UI expectations? Suggest box? Multiselect widget? Table with checkboxes?...

Comment: Thanks very much Pavel for the reply. Its a simple UI, for this app, I will need only a multiselect widget, a couple of dropdowns (each one displaying the records of the respective datasources).

Comment: Desoss, that works well for one to many relations, but I could not do it for a many to many relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With many-to-many relation on the object/api level App Maker gives an array of related records. Let's say we have 'Questions' and 'Tags' models with many-to-many relation. We can create association from any end of the relation:

```javascript
// create association from question side
question.Tags.push(tag);

// create association from tag side
tag.Questions.push(question);
```

[Multiselect Widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#MultiSelect) will do this work for. Let's say we need to add some tags for a questions and we need to bind multiselect to all tags we have in our DB then binding will look similar to this

```javascript
// binding for Multiselect's names (.. - two dots mean projection)
@datasources.Tags.items..Name

// binding for Multiselect's options
@datasources.Tags.items

// binding for Multiselect's values
// assuming that parent widget is bound to datasource with question
// and `@datasource.item` is question
@datasource.item.Tags
```

with [Suggest Box](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#SuggestBox) and [Dropdown](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Dropdown) widgets binding will be similar to multiselect's one but you'll need to do some scripting:

```javascript
// onValueEdit event handler
// assuming that parent widget is bound to datasource with question
widget.datasource.item.Tags.push(newValue);
```

Comment: Thanks a million Pavel! Excellent explanation and a brilliant solution, it worked very well. Much appreciated!

Comment: How would you change this is you wanted the options to not just be what's already in the database, but rather a pre-determined list of options? Let's say you have 10 set tags to pick from. What would change above? When I try to use @model.ModelName.fields.NameField.possibleValues the option select it is grayed out, and I can't figure out why

Comment: You can create many to many associations only between records persisted in a database. `possibleValues` is just a list of strings/numbers. It sounds that you can just to use a field to store comma-separated values and bind them on UI with transformer (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/transformers#strToArray).