# Multi-Select Suggest Box?

Tags: google-app-maker

This question is somewhat building off of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897894/how-to-populate-many-to-many-relationship/49927422#49927422) regarding how to add and view Many-to-Many relations.

I have one Model called Contacts with a Many-to-Many relation to itself (Children and Parents).

If I go to a Child Item, I want to be able to have a field called Parents, where I can select the Child's parents. Since the Model will have hundreds of contact items, a Multi-Select widget would not be practical. I need the suggest box functionality to make it easy to find and select the Parents. However, a Suggest Box alone just seems to be able to hold one value, so the question is, how can I use a Suggest Box to set multiple values that are easily added and removed? It would be like having the result of a Suggest Box added to a Multi-Select field.

How might this be possible?

Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at Training Hub template - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/training-hub/, AssignCourses page

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful (although in my case I want the selected Parent items to be added directly as a relation to the current Child item; not to a custom properties field which I presume is because the Assign button will create the item and relations). I will try and tweak the code as that example provides a useful example. Thank you!